# SwiftMailer setBody with database

Tags: symfony, twig, swiftmailer

I have a problem to send a mail, since symfony 2.8 with SwiftMailer.
Before, I used this method :

```
$body = $this->twig->render($email->getCorp());
```

With an external service, but now I have this error :

> Unable to find template "`<div>`...template in database..."

I've tried this too, and I've got the same error :

```
$email = $em->getRepository('BoAdminBundle:Email')->find(3);
$body = $this->render($email->getCorp());
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Subject')
                    ->setFrom('mail@mail.com')
                    ->setTo($insti->getEmail())
                    ->setContentType("text/html")
                    ->setBody($body);
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Thanks for your help :) !

**EDIT** :

```
    $parametersFinal = array_merge($replaces, $replacesInsti); // $replacesInsti = array the client's informations

    $body = $this->twig->render($email->getCorp(), $parametersFinal);
```

How can I insert this "$parametersFinal" in the body ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't understand the context you're in. Could you please provide a little more information about the context? What does `$this` refer to? Is it a controller, a service or anything else? Thanks

Comment: It's in a service that use Twig and SwiftMailer, and then it's called in a controller. The second try in my post was a test in the controller directly.

Thx for helping !

Comment: What does `$email->getCorp()` return?

Comment: A field in the database that contains the html message (body of the email).

Comment: Your edit seems like it might be better serviced as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, the HTML exists by calling the `getCorp()` function, in which case your code should instead be:

```
$email = $em->getRepository('BoAdminBundle:Email')->find(3);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Subject')
    ->setFrom('mail@mail.com')
    ->setTo($insti->getEmail())
    ->setContentType("text/html")
    ->setBody($email->getCorp())
;
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

The `render()` function expects the name of a template to render as its first argument, and an optional array of parameters to pass to that template.

Comment: Yes, it's works ! 
Thanks a lot !

Now I'll edit the post because i need to insert twig parameters in the html body.